# NixOS <crypt.h> missing when installing a Perl module from CPAN

Tags: nixos, nix, cpan

I'm fairly new to NixOS, but I'm trying to install `App::cpm` from CPAN.

I run the following:

```
cpan -i App::cpm
```

It chugs for a little bit then, it fails on `Build::Tiny`:

```
crypt.h: No such file or directory
  124 | #      include <crypt.h>
```

I looked through NixPkgs to try to see where the header lives, but I can't find anywhere to install this. I assume it's a `systemPackage`. Thanks.

Comment: Libraries are not supposed to be installed globally with Nix, see https://nixos.wiki/wiki/FAQ#I_installed_a_library_but_my_compiler_is_not_finding_it._Why.3F

Answer (score 1):

You should typically install the packages directly from nix if it is available, as it will automatically take care of compiling stuff if needed (in your tests, it is trying to compile it but C library are not available outside of build commands so it fails… if you really want you can certainly drop into a `nix-shell -p gcc` but there is not so much benefit here since `cpm` is already packaged). For instance, here if you just type:

```
$ nix-shell -p perl perlPackages.Appcpm
```

you will get into a shell with cpm installed. The precise name of the package can be searched in [https://search.nixos.org](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=cpm) (or directly [in the source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/top-level/perl-packages.nix))